# Biblatex customization not working

Tags: biblatex

I'm working on my assignments for Study and unfortunately I'm too silly to understand the library... Currently the authoryear context is declared:

```
--> See executable
```

I already figured out how to change some basic things like the comma in the citation and how to change the url to display without monospace and without prefix. Unfortunately now, the hypenation is damaged and no linefeed is inserted. Here is my code for customizing (file `modsBiblatex.tex`):

```
% Optionen für Biblatex
\ExecuteBibliographyOptions{%
giveninits=false,
isbn=true, 
url=true, 
doi=false, 
eprint=false,
maxbibnames=7, % Alle Autoren (kein et al.)
maxcitenames=1, % Kürzel nur aus 1. Autor
backref=false, % Rückverweise auf Zitatseiten
bibencoding=utf8, % wenn .bib in utf8, sonst ascii
bibwarn=true, % Warnung bei fehlerhafter bib-Datei
}%


%Autoren (Nachname, Vorname)
\DeclareNameAlias{default}{last-first}

\renewcommand*{\nameyeardelim}{\addcomma\addspace} % insert a comma between author and year in-text citations


%Titel nicht kursiv anzeigen 
\DeclareFieldFormat{title}{\mkbibquote{#1\isdot}}

% Sourcecode nicht in codecoloumn anzeigen
\DeclareFieldFormat{url}{\url{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat{urldate}{#1}

\renewcommand*{\newunitpunct}{\addcomma\space}

% Definiert @Online Eintrag
\DeclareBibliographyDriver{www}{%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printnames{author}%
  \setunit*{\addcomma\space}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{title}%
  \newunit\newblock
%  \setunit*{\space}%
  \printfield{url}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \setunit*{\addcomma\space accessed \space}%
  \printfield{urldate}%
  \finentry}
```

The part `\DeclareBibliographyDriver` is not working for me. I already gave up to find information how to customize this. May someone know a page where this function is explained so a noob like me can understand it?
Nethertheless my most important question is: How can I change the `url` field to include an automatic linebreak again?

Bib example (file `economics.bib`):

```
@online{EuropeanCentralBank.2017,
 abstract = {The three official interest rates the ECB sets every six weeks as part of its monetary policy to steer the provision of liquidity to the banking sector.},
 author = {{European Central Bank}},
 year = {2017},
 title = {Key ECB interest rates},
 url = {https://www.ecb.europa.eu/stats/policy_and_exchange_rates/key_ecb_interest_rates-/html/index.en.html},
 address = {Frankfurt am Main},
 urldate = {12.08.2017}
}


@online{EuropeanCentralBank.2017b,
 author = {{European Central Bank}},
 editor = {{European Central Bank}},
 year = {2017},
 title = {Why are stable prices important?},
 url = {https://www.ecb.europa.eu/explainers/tell-me-more/html/stableprices.en.html},
 urldate = {14.08.2017}
}


@online{EuropeanCentralBank.2017c,
 abstract = {Information on the scope of the ECB's monetary policy.},
 author = {{European Central Bank}},
 year = {2017},
 title = {Scope of monetary policy},
 url = {https://www.ecb.europa.eu/mopo/intro/role/html/index.en.html},
 address = {Frankfurt am Main},
 urldate = {14.08.2017}
}


@online{EuropeanCentralBank.2017d,
 abstract = {Maintaining price stability: Learn more about the objective of the ECB's monetary policy.},
 author = {{European Central Bank}},
 year = {2017},
 title = {Objective of monetary policy},
 url = {https://www.ecb.europa.eu/mopo/intro/objective/html/index.en.html},
 address = {Frankfurt am Main},
 urldate = {14.08.2017}
}


@online{EuropeanCentralBank.2017e,
 author = {{European Central Bank}},
 year = {2017},
 title = {Monetary policy decisions},
 url = {https://www.ecb.europa.eu/press/pr/date/2017/html/ecb.mp170720.en.html},
 address = {Frankfurt am Main},
 urldate = {12.08.2017}
}


@online{EuropeanCentralBank.2017f,
 abstract = {Monetary aggregates and counterparts are derived from the euro area banks' (MFIs') consolidated balance sheet. Monetary aggregates comprise short-term liabilities vis-{\`a}-vis the money holding sector, i.e. non-bank euro area residents excluding central government.},
 author = {{European Central Bank}},
 year = {2017},
 title = {Monetary aggregates},
 url = {https://www.ecb.europa.eu/stats/money_credit_banking/monetary_aggregates/html/index.en.html},
 address = {Frankfurt am Main},
 urldate = {12.08.2017}
}
```

This is the executable (I deleted as much as possible):

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside,titlepage,listof=totoc,bibliography=totoc]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman,USenglish]{babel}
\usepackage[autostyle,english=british]{csquotes}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{fancybox}
\usepackage[a4paper, left=4cm, right=2cm, top=2.8cm, bottom=2.3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{refstyle}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{float}      %Positionierung von Abb. und Tabellen mit [H] erzwingen
\usepackage{footnote}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{marvosym}           % Verwendung von Symbolen, z.B. perfektes Eurozeichen
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,linkcolor=black]{hyperref}
\definecolor{darkblack}{rgb}{0,0,0}
\hypersetup{colorlinks=true, breaklinks=true, linkcolor=darkblack, menucolor=darkblack, urlcolor=darkblack}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{eurosym}           % Einbinden von offiziellen Eurosymbolen
%\usepackage{nth}               % Bibliothek um das th (eg. 4th of ...) an Datumangaben hochzustellen.
\fontfamily{ptm}\selectfont

% Biblatex
\usepackage[
backend=biber,
style=authoryear,
citestyle=authoryear,
url=false,
isbn=false,
%notetype=footonly,
hyperref=false,
sortlocale=de]{biblatex}

%weitere Anpassungen für BibLaTex
\input{skripte/modsBiblatex}

%Bib-Datei einbinden
\addbibresource{literatur/economics.bib}

%-----------------------------------
% Start the document here:
%-----------------------------------
\begin{document}

This is a text referencing the bib entrys \parencite{EuropeanCentralBank.2017,EuropeanCentralBank.2017b,EuropeanCentralBank.2017c,EuropeanCentralBank.2017d,EuropeanCentralBank.2017e,EuropeanCentralBank.2017f}

\pagenumbering{Roman}                               % Seitennumerierung auf römisch umstellen
\renewcommand{\refname}{Literature}                 % "Literatur" in
%"Literaturverzeichnis" umbenennen
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}    % Neuer Tabellen-Spalten-Typ:
%Zentriert und umbrechbar


%-----------------------------------
% Literaturverzeichnis
%-----------------------------------
\newpage
%\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Literatur}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

My Questions:
- Do you know any easy documentation for customizing of the bibliography and the drivers?
- Do you know how to get the hypenation in an URL without displaying in monospace? (I need Roman)
- What is the reason, the field `urldate`  and the prefix "accessed" is not displayed?

Comment: Could you try with `online` instead of `www` in your `\DeclareBibliographyDriver`? Even though `www` is indeed defined as an alias of `online` by biblatex, I'm not sure it expects the alias for the driver definitions.

Comment: Don't show snippets, make a complete example that can be tested. Also don't burry too many questions in a long text. The url doesn't break as you removed the `\url` command in the field format. Use `\DeclareFieldFormat{url}{\url{#1}}`.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thanks alot, this helped to get back the hypenation. But now I'm still figuring the problem the link is displayed in monospace, I want it as Roman, like the rest of the text. May you also got a solution for this?

Comment: @gusbrs Thanks for your hint, I changed the bib file to online, but it changed nothing in the result. But I will change my Citavi export to deliver online sources as "online" tag.

Comment: `\urlstyle{rm}` should work (untested).

Comment: Then I guess, as already suggested by Ulrike, that we'll need a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) (in your case, a [MWEB](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407)). That should be compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`, that illustrates your problem. You can edit your question to include it.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Question has been edited. The command urlstyle worked for me, many thanks!

Comment: Please ask only one question per question. It is much easier for us to answer then. There is no shame in asking several questions if they are thought through and provide all the necessary information.

Comment: Regarding bibliography customization, you could take a look at [Guidelines for customizing biblatex styles](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12806/105447) and, of course, biblatex's documentation.

Comment: You don't get to see the access date, because your `urldate` fields are not formatted correctly. Regardless of what you want the output to be, the date input must be in the form `YYYY-MM-DD`, so only `urldate = {2017-08-17}` would be correct.

Comment: `style=authoryear, citestyle=authoryear,` is equivalent to, the shorter `style=authoryear`. In newer versions of `biblatex` (>=3.3, current version is 3.7), `\DeclareNameAlias{default}{last-first}` should be `\DeclareNameAlias{default}{family-given}`.

Comment: As Ulrike explained `\DeclareBibliographyDriver{www}` won't work, because `@www` is just an alias for `@online`. Internally `biblatex` only knows `online`. Biber actually converts all `@www`s to `@online`s. So you must use `\DeclareBibliographyDriver{online}` in your customisation code.

Comment: @gusbrs Thanks again. Both I already tryed to understand within the last week, but i did not get it. The biblatex documentation is for me just a syntax sheet, not more. Maybe I can understand it, when I got even more knowledge. In my view, it's nothing for beginners.
The Guideline, helped me a bit, but it was too short for the understanding I need to change the Bibliography for the Harvard style.

Comment: We don't have the content of your `\input{skripte/modsBiblatex}`, so we still don't have a code that is compilable from our point of view. Also, I'm not sure what you mean by `\DeclareBibliographyDriver` "doesn't work", you'll have to be more specific than that. Taking your code (after adjustments) and using `\DeclareBibliographyDriver{online}` as already suggested here, it does work as intended, in the sense that the formating does follow what's contained there (to see, delete some of the lines, if you wish).

Comment: I don't know of any good literature for the 'intermediate' `biblatex` user that wants to apply modifications and customisations in English. There are some great introductory texts linked in [biblatex in a nutshell (for beginners)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/13509/35864), a few of them cover more than just the basics, but they don't explain all the customisation options. In German there is the classic http://biblatex.dominik-wassenhoven.de/nutzungsbedingungen.shtml?biblatex1 and http://biblatex.dominik-wassenhoven.de/nutzungsbedingungen.shtml?biblatex2

Comment: ... But these articles were written a while ago, and development has moved on a bit since then. So a few things can now be done more easily, a few command names have changed etc. There is also http://texwelt.de/blog/modifizieren-eines-biblatex-stils/ I'm not happy with everything that is done there, but the rough overview is good (https://gitlab.com/Ekkehardt/dok-biblatex-iest is newer and does some things better).

Comment: Many thanks for all of you. I will check the documentations and in the case I cannot manage to change the contents as I need them, I will create a new question.

Comment: The options `giveninits=false, isbn=true,  url=true,` are all the default, so you don't have to set them explicitly.

Answer (score 4):

At last you have three questions here:

1. Do you know any easy documentation for customizing of the bibliography and the drivers?

   The problem here is what you mean with "easy". I think that is a personal opinion. The "best" documentation is the documentation comming with package `biblatex`. You can read it with `texdoc biblatex` from your terminal.
2. Do you know how to get the hypenation in an URL without displaying in monospace? (I need Roman)

   To get the url printed in roman use the command `\urlstyle{rm}`. To get the hyphenation back use the command `\url` from package `url`: `\DeclareFieldFormat{url}{\url{#1}}`
3. What is the reason, the field urldate and the prefix "accessed" is not displayed?

   You used a wrong date format in your bib entrys, for example `urldate = {12.08.2017}`.  The correct format is yyyy-mm-dd, so please use `urldate = {2017-08-12}`

I combined your given code snippets to a compilable code and marked all imortant changes with `<======` in the code.

The following MWE

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@online{EuropeanCentralBank.2017,
 abstract = {The three official interest rates the ECB sets every six weeks as part of its monetary policy to steer the provision of liquidity to the banking sector.},
 author = {{European Central Bank}},
 year = {2017},
 title = {Key ECB interest rates},
 url = {https://www.ecb.europa.eu/stats/policy_and_exchange_rates/key_ecb_interest_rates-/html/index.en.html},
 address = {Frankfurt am Main},
 urldate = {2017-08-12}
}
@online{EuropeanCentralBank.2017b,
 author = {{European Central Bank}},
 editor = {{European Central Bank}},
 year = {2017},
 title = {Why are stable prices important?},
 url = {https://www.ecb.europa.eu/explainers/tell-me-more/html/stableprices.en.html},
 urldate = {2017-08-12}
}
@online{EuropeanCentralBank.2017c,
 abstract = {Information on the scope of the ECB's monetary policy.},
 author = {{European Central Bank}},
 year = {2017},
 title = {Scope of monetary policy},
 url = {https://www.ecb.europa.eu/mopo/intro/role/html/index.en.html},
 address = {Frankfurt am Main},
 urldate = {2017-08-12}
}
@online{EuropeanCentralBank.2017d,
 abstract = {Maintaining price stability: Learn more about the objective of the ECB's monetary policy.},
 author = {{European Central Bank}},
 year = {2017},
 title = {Objective of monetary policy},
 url = {https://www.ecb.europa.eu/mopo/intro/objective/html/index.en.html},
 address = {Frankfurt am Main},
 urldate = {2017-08-12}
}
@online{EuropeanCentralBank.2017e,
 author = {{European Central Bank}},
 year = {2017},
 title = {Monetary policy decisions},
 url = {https://www.ecb.europa.eu/press/pr/date/2017/html/ecb.mp170720.en.html},
 address = {Frankfurt am Main},
 urldate = {2017-08-12}
}
@online{EuropeanCentralBank.2017f,
 abstract = {Monetary aggregates and counterparts are derived from the euro area banks' (MFIs') consolidated balance sheet. Monetary aggregates comprise short-term liabilities vis-{\`a}-vis the money holding sector, i.e. non-bank euro area residents excluding central government.},
 author = {{European Central Bank}},
 year = {2017},
 title = {Monetary aggregates},
 url = {https://www.ecb.europa.eu/stats/money_credit_banking/monetary_aggregates/html/index.en.html},
 address = {Frankfurt am Main},
 urldate = {2017-08-12}
}
\end{filecontents}


\documentclass[12pt,oneside,titlepage,listof=totoc,bibliography=totoc]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman,USenglish]{babel}
\usepackage[autostyle,english=british]{csquotes}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[%
  a4paper, left=4cm, right=2cm, top=2.8cm, bottom=2.3cm,
  showframe % <=========================================================
]{geometry}

% Biblatex
\usepackage[%
  backend=biber,  
  style=authoryear,
% citestyle=authoryear, % <=============================================
  url=false,
  isbn=false,
% notetype=footonly,
  hyperref=false,
  sortlocale=de
]{biblatex}

\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,linkcolor=black]{hyperref}
\definecolor{darkblack}{rgb}{0,0,0}
\hypersetup{colorlinks=true, breaklinks=true, linkcolor=darkblack, 
            menucolor=darkblack, urlcolor=darkblack}

% Optionen für Biblatex
\ExecuteBibliographyOptions{%
  giveninits=false,
  isbn=true, 
  url=true, 
  doi=false, 
  eprint=false,
  maxbibnames=7, % Alle Autoren (kein et al.)
  maxcitenames=1, % Kürzel nur aus 1. Autor
  backref=false, % Rückverweise auf Zitatseiten
  bibencoding=utf8, % wenn .bib in utf8, sonst ascii
  bibwarn=true, % Warnung bei fehlerhafter bib-Datei
}%

%Autoren (Nachname, Vorname)
\DeclareNameAlias{default}{family-given} % <============================

\renewcommand*{\nameyeardelim}{\addcomma\addspace} % insert a comma between author and year in-text citations

%Titel nicht kursiv anzeigen 
\DeclareFieldFormat{title}{\mkbibquote{#1\isdot}}

% Sourcecode nicht in codecoloumn anzeigen
\DeclareFieldFormat{url}{\url{#1}} % <==================================
\urlstyle{rm} % <=======================================================
\DeclareFieldFormat{urldate}{#1}

\renewcommand*{\newunitpunct}{\addcomma\space}

% Definiert @Online Eintrag
\DeclareBibliographyDriver{online}{% www <==============================
  \newunit\newblock
  \printnames{author}%
  \setunit*{\addcomma\space}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{title}%
  \newunit\newblock
% \setunit*{\space}%
  \printfield{url}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \setunit*{\addcomma\space accessed \space}%
  \printfield{urldate}%
  \finentry}

%Bib-Datei einbinden
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib} % <======= to used the bib file created with filecontents


%-----------------------------------
% Start the document here:
%-----------------------------------
\begin{document}

This is a text referencing the bib entrys 
\parencite{EuropeanCentralBank.2017,EuropeanCentralBank.2017b,
  EuropeanCentralBank.2017c,EuropeanCentralBank.2017d,
  EuropeanCentralBank.2017e,EuropeanCentralBank.2017f}

\pagenumbering{Roman}                % Seitennumerierung auf römisch umstellen
\renewcommand{\refname}{Literature}  % "Literatur" in "Literaturverzeichnis" umbenennen

%-----------------------------------
% Literaturverzeichnis
%-----------------------------------
%\newpage
%\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Literatur}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

gives the result:

[image: resulting pdf]

Your **4th question** is why `\DeclareBibliographyDriver{www}` is not working.  Because `www` is only an alias, change `www` to `online`. It seems that `urldate` is not propperly defined and so it is not printed with your own driver. A quick workaround could be to change `\printfield{urldate}%` to use `urlday`, `urlmonth` and `urlyear` instead (change the order as you need):

```
\DeclareBibliographyDriver{online}{% www <==============================
  \newunit\newblock
  \printnames{author}%
  \setunit*{\addcomma\space}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{title}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{url}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \setunit*{\addcomma\space accessed \space}%
  \printfield{urlyear}\printtext{-}\printfield{urlmonth}\printtext{-}\printfield{urlday}% <=================================
  \finentry}
```

Then you get the following result:

[image: better solution]

If you define the filed for `urldate` like this:

```
\DeclareFieldFormat{urldate}{\addcomma\space\printtext{accessed}\space #1}
```

you get an comma, then "accessed" and the date in the current form, if you comment out your own driver for `online`.  A driver `online` is already defined with more functionality than your own.

With a changed bib entry (added editor and note to the first entry)  you get the result

[image]

with the following MWE:

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@online{EuropeanCentralBank.2017,
  abstract = {The three official interest rates the ECB sets every six 
              weeks as part of its monetary policy to steer the provision 
              of liquidity to the banking sector.},
  author = {{European Central Bank}},
  editor = {John Doe},
  year = {2017},
  title = {Key ECB interest rates},
  url = {https://www.ecb.europa.eu/stats/policy_and_exchange_rates/key_ecb_interest_rates-/html/index.en.html},
  address = {Frankfurt am Main},
  urldate = {2017-08-12},
  note = {testnote testnote testnote},
}
@online{EuropeanCentralBank.2017b,
 author = {{European Central Bank}},
 editor = {{European Central Bank}},
 year = {2017},
 title = {Why are stable prices important?},
 url = {https://www.ecb.europa.eu/explainers/tell-me-more/html/stableprices.en.html},
 urldate = {2017-08-12}
}
@online{EuropeanCentralBank.2017c,
 abstract = {Information on the scope of the ECB's monetary policy.},
 author = {{European Central Bank}},
 year = {2017},
 title = {Scope of monetary policy},
 url = {https://www.ecb.europa.eu/mopo/intro/role/html/index.en.html},
 address = {Frankfurt am Main},
 urldate = {2017-08-12}
}
@online{EuropeanCentralBank.2017d,
 abstract = {Maintaining price stability: Learn more about the objective of the ECB's monetary policy.},
 author = {{European Central Bank}},
 year = {2017},
 title = {Objective of monetary policy},
 url = {https://www.ecb.europa.eu/mopo/intro/objective/html/index.en.html},
 address = {Frankfurt am Main},
 urldate = {2017-08-12}
}
@online{EuropeanCentralBank.2017e,
 author = {{European Central Bank}},
 year = {2017},
 title = {Monetary policy decisions},
 url = {https://www.ecb.europa.eu/press/pr/date/2017/html/ecb.mp170720.en.html},
 address = {Frankfurt am Main},
 urldate = {2017-08-12}
}
@online{EuropeanCentralBank.2017f,
 abstract = {Monetary aggregates and counterparts are derived from the euro area banks' (MFIs') consolidated balance sheet. Monetary aggregates comprise short-term liabilities vis-{\`a}-vis the money holding sector, i.e. non-bank euro area residents excluding central government.},
 author = {{European Central Bank}},
 year = {2017},
 title = {Monetary aggregates},
 url = {https://www.ecb.europa.eu/stats/money_credit_banking/monetary_aggregates/html/index.en.html},
 address = {Frankfurt am Main},
 urldate = {2017-08-12}
}
\end{filecontents}


\documentclass[12pt,oneside,titlepage,listof=totoc,bibliography=totoc]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman,USenglish]{babel}
\usepackage[autostyle,english=british]{csquotes}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[%
  a4paper, left=4cm, right=2cm, top=2.8cm, bottom=2.3cm,
  showframe % <=========================================================
]{geometry}

% Biblatex
\usepackage[%
  backend=biber,  
  style=authoryear,
% citestyle=authoryear, % <=============================================
% notetype=footonly,
  hyperref=false,
  sortlocale=de,
  giveninits=false,
  isbn=true, 
  url=true, 
  doi=false, 
  eprint=false,
  maxbibnames=7, % Alle Autoren (kein et al.)
  maxcitenames=1, % Kürzel nur aus 1. Autor
  backref=false, % Rückverweise auf Zitatseiten
  bibencoding=utf8, % wenn .bib in utf8, sonst ascii
  bibwarn=true, % Warnung bei fehlerhafter bib-Datei
]{biblatex}

\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,linkcolor=black]{hyperref}
\definecolor{darkblack}{rgb}{0,0,0}
\hypersetup{%
  colorlinks=true, 
  breaklinks=true, 
  linkcolor=darkblack, 
  menucolor=darkblack, 
  urlcolor=darkblack
}

%Autoren (Nachname, Vorname)
\DeclareNameAlias{default}{family-given} % <============================

\renewcommand*{\nameyeardelim}{\addcomma\addspace} % insert a comma between author and year in-text citations

%Titel nicht kursiv anzeigen 
\DeclareFieldFormat{title}{\mkbibquote{#1\isdot}}

% Sourcecode nicht in codecoloumn anzeigen
\DeclareFieldFormat{url}{\url{#1}} % <==================================
\urlstyle{rm} % <=======================================================
\DeclareFieldFormat{urldate}{\addcomma\space\printtext{accessed}\space #1} % <===============

\renewcommand*{\newunitpunct}{\addcomma\space}

% Definiert @Online Eintrag
%\DeclareBibliographyDriver{online}{% www <==============================
  %\newunit\newblock
  %\printnames{author}%
  %\setunit*{\addcomma\space}%
  %\newunit\newblock
  %\printfield{title}%
  %\newunit\newblock
  %\printfield{url}%
  %\newunit\newblock
  %\setunit*{\addcomma\space accessed \space}%
  %\printfield{urlyear}\printtext{-}\printfield{urlmonth}\printtext{-}\printfield{urlday}% <===========================================
  %%\printfield{urldate}
  %\finentry}


%Bib-Datei einbinden
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib} % <======= to used the bib file created with filecontents


%-----------------------------------
% Start the document here:
%-----------------------------------
\begin{document}

This is a text referencing the bib entrys 
\parencite{EuropeanCentralBank.2017,EuropeanCentralBank.2017b,
  EuropeanCentralBank.2017c,EuropeanCentralBank.2017d,
  EuropeanCentralBank.2017e,EuropeanCentralBank.2017f}

\pagenumbering{Roman}                % Seitennumerierung auf römisch umstellen
\renewcommand{\refname}{Literature}  % "Literatur" in "Literaturverzeichnis" umbenennen

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do things in a less complicated way than in the other answer (especially in relation to `urldate` handling).

But there are still a number of confusing points in your original question.

e.g.,

- Do you want ‘British’ or “American” style quotes?
- Do you want German (12.08.2017) or American (08/12/2017) style short dates?
- Do you want *all* titles enquoted or just ones for `online` entry types?
- Do you *really* want the `date` field suppressed in your bibliography? (The `date` field should contain the date the article was written and `urldate`, the date you accessed it). I've left it in.

I've also not rewritten the driver as you will lose a lot of functionality and flexibility if you do this. It's better to modify individual bibmacros or clear fields at every bibliography item to tweak your output.

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@online{EuropeanCentralBank.2017,
 author = {{European Central Bank}},
 year = {2017},
 title = {Key ECB interest rates},
 url = {https://www.ecb.europa.eu/stats/policy_and_exchange_rates/key_ecb_interest_rates-/html/index.en.html},
 address = {Frankfurt am Main},
 urldate = {2017-08-12}
}
@online{EuropeanCentralBank.2017b,
 author = {{European Central Bank}},
 editor = {{European Central Bank}},
 year = {2017},
 title = {Why are stable prices important?},
 url = {https://www.ecb.europa.eu/explainers/tell-me-more/html/stableprices.en.html},
 urldate = {2017-08-12}
}
@online{EuropeanCentralBank.2017c,
 abstract = {Information on the scope of the ECB's monetary policy.},
 author = {{European Central Bank}},
 year = {2017},
 title = {Scope of monetary policy},
 url = {https://www.ecb.europa.eu/mopo/intro/role/html/index.en.html},
 address = {Frankfurt am Main},
 urldate = {2017-08-12}
}
@online{EuropeanCentralBank.2017d,
 abstract = {Maintaining price stability: Learn more about the objective of the ECB's monetary policy.},
 author = {{European Central Bank}},
 year = {2017},
 title = {Objective of monetary policy},
 url = {https://www.ecb.europa.eu/mopo/intro/objective/html/index.en.html},
 address = {Frankfurt am Main},
 urldate = {2017-08-12}
}
@online{EuropeanCentralBank.2017e,
 author = {{European Central Bank}},
 year = {2017},
 title = {Monetary policy decisions},
 url = {https://www.ecb.europa.eu/press/pr/date/2017/html/ecb.mp170720.en.html},
 address = {Frankfurt am Main},
 urldate = {2017-08-12}
}
@online{EuropeanCentralBank.2017f,
 author = {{European Central Bank}},
 year = {2017},
 title = {Monetary aggregates},
 url = {https://www.ecb.europa.eu/stats/money_credit_banking/monetary_aggregates/html/index.en.html},
 address = {Frankfurt am Main},
 urldate = {2017-08-12}
}
\end{filecontents}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\usepackage[ngerman,american]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=authoryear,sortlocale=de,doi=false,eprint=false,
            maxbibnames=7,maxcitenames=1,dashed=false]{biblatex}
% use a comma between fields in bibliography
\renewcommand*{\newunitpunct}{\addcomma\space}
% use a comma between name and year in citations
\renewcommand*{\nameyeardelim}{\addcomma\addspace}
% set name format to family, given
\DeclareNameAlias{default}{family-given}
% enquote *all* titles (is this what you want?)
\DeclareFieldFormat{title}{\mkbibquote{#1\isdot}}
% remove ᴜʀʟ: prefix
\DeclareFieldFormat{url}{\url{#1}}
% remove parentheses around urldate
\DeclareFieldFormat{urldate}{\bibstring{urlseen}\space#1}
% Roman style urls
\urlstyle{rm}
% comma instead of space between url and urldate
\xpatchbibmacro{url+urldate}
  {\setunit*{\addspace}}
  {\newunit}
  {}{}
\AtEveryBibitem{%
  \ifentrytype{online}
    {% don't print date (is this really what you want?)
     \renewbibmacro*{date+extrayear}{}%
     % don't print editor (but what if there is no author?)
     \clearname{editor}%
     % don't print translator (but what if there is no editor or author?)
     \clearname{translator}}
    {}}
% redefine urlseen string to be accessed
\DefineBibliographyStrings{american}{%
  urlseen = {accessed}
}
% use German style short dates (is this what you want?)
% this is taken from german.lbx
\DefineBibliographyExtras{american}{%
  \protected\def\mkbibdateshort#1#2#3{%
    \iffieldundef{#3}
      {}
      {\mkdayzeros{\thefield{#3}}\adddot
       \iffieldundef{#2}{}{\thinspace}}%
    \iffieldundef{#2}
      {}
      {\mkmonthzeros{\thefield{#2}}%
       \iffieldundef{#1}
     {}
     {\iffieldundef{#3}{/}{\adddot\thinspace}}}%
    \iffieldbibstring{#1}
      {\bibstring{\thefield{#1}}}
      {\dateeraprintpre{#1}\mkyearzeros{\thefield{#1}}}}%
}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\parencite{EuropeanCentralBank.2017,EuropeanCentralBank.2017b,
  EuropeanCentralBank.2017c,EuropeanCentralBank.2017d,
  EuropeanCentralBank.2017e,EuropeanCentralBank.2017f}
\printbibliography[title=Literatur]
\end{document}
```

[image]